# RoR: Controller Submit with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I'm writing an entry submission controller by this tutorial: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/1

When I try to submit an entry, I get `Users can't be blank`...I don't want to pass the user_id in as a hidden field, right? So how should I change this to automatically get the user's id?

I'm using devise for authentication. :) And I'm a complete rails novice.
This is my controller:

```
    def submit
      @entry = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])

      # submit only, if article is currently in draft or rejected-state
      if (@entry.state == 0) or (@article.state == 2)
        @entry.state = 1
        @entry.submitted = Time.now

        if @entry.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Your article was successfully submitted for approval.'
        else
          flash[:error] = 'There was an error while submitting your article.'   
        end           
      else
        flash[:error] = 'This article can not be submitted.'  
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:action => 'myarticles') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
    end
  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /entries
  # POST /entries.xml
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@entry, :notice => 'Entry was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /entries/1
  # PUT /entries/1.xml
  def update
    @entry = current_user.entries.find(params[:id])

        #if the entry has been approved, the user cannot change the title or URL.
        if @entry.state > 2
            params[:entry].delete(:title)
            params[:entry].delete(:url)
        end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
        format.html { redirect_to(@entry, :notice => 'Entry was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems that you would encounter this error when trying to create a new Entry.

```
  def create
    @entry = current_user.entries.new(params[:entry]) # <-- Scope to the current user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@entry, :notice => 'Entry was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end    
  end
```

Comment: Also, you'll want to do the same thing for the edit action.  `@entry = current_user.entries.find(params[:id])`  So that a user cannot edit another user's entries.

Comment: Alrightie! Thanks. :)  Would you give a little more explanation for me?  Like I said, I'm new--I don't exactly understand what you mean by `scope to`...

Comment: `Entry.find(params[:id])` can find any Entry record in your database,  but quite often you want users to only access records that belong to them. In your edit action above any user could edit any Entry if they knew (or guessed) the id.  It is common practice to prevent this problem by limiting the find to only return Entries that belong to the current user.  `current_user.entries.find(params[:id])` does just that by adding a WHERE condition to the SQL query like `WHERE entries.user_id=123`